# How to select objects with specific IDs from a JSON array with jq?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON file containing an array of objects (*test.json*):

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test 1",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Test 2",
        "id": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Test 3",
        "id": 3
    }
]
```

I want to extract all objects, that have a certain ID. I managed to get an object if I want just one specific ID: `jq 'map(select(.id == 2 ))' test.json`.

Thing is, I have a list of IDs, say 1 and 3. How do I get a list containing only those object? So in this example a list containing the objects with ID 1 and 3?

You can check the example here: https://jqplay.org/s/xQgpA4yJAz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jq 'map(select(.id | contains(1,3)))'`

Man, jq is so great

https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#filter-objects-based-on-the-contents-of-a-key

Comment: This operator is so confusing. I never know if `a|contains(b)` means "a contains b" or "b contains a". Sometimes I don’t even know: `echo '["aa", "bb"]' | jq 'contains(["a", "b"])'` outputs `true`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `contains/1` as presented on this page could just as well be written using `==`:

```
map(select(.id == (1,3)))
```

The main reason for mentioning this is that `contains` is full of potential surprises. (Consider, for example, what would happen if `.id` were string-valued.)

Unfortunately, using either `==` or `contains` as above is computationally inefficient (it is O(m*n)), though in practice it is quite fast.